# Inequality involving $\ell_p$-sum of matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A_1, \cdots, A_n, B_1, \cdots, B_n$ be square matrices of same dimension, and suppose that $\left|A_i\right| \leq \left|B_i\right|$ for every $1 \leq i \leq n$.

Is it true that $\Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left|A_i\right|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left|B_i\right|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ for any $p \in [1, \infty)$?

**Edit:** Is $\Big\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left|A_i\right|^p\Big\| \leq \Big\|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left|B_i\right|^p\Big\|$? What about $\Big\|\Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left|A_i\right|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big\| \leq \Big\|\Big(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \left|B_i\right|^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}\Big\|$? What if we consider the Schatten norms?

Comment: What do you mean by the modulus of a matrix $A$? The square root of $A^*A$?

Comment: It looks false, because $(1+|A|^2)^{1/2}\approx 1+\frac{1}{2}|A|^2$ for small $A$.

Comment: Yes, @JochenGlueck!

Comment: Hmm, yes, it looks false, @NarutakaOZAWA. Thank you! I edited the question.

Comment: Try editing again. With Ai on both sides the answer is yes :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @Derek ;-)

Comment: As a note to @NarutakaOZAWA's answer: if $0 \leq A \leq B$ then, using https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1622770/245249, we may prove that $\lambda_k(1 + A^p) \leq \lambda_k(1 + B^p)$ for any $k$, and therefore we have norm inequalities.